How can I record video defaulting to the panoramic lense?
I want to record video defaulting to the panoramic (0.5x, 16 mm, wide angle) lense on my Motorola Razr 2022. Currently the builtin camera app defaults to the normal (10x, 23 mm) lense every time I exit/enter the app, or the phone locks/unlocks. Sometimes I forget to switch it back at the moment I hit record. I can't monitor the phone while it is recording because it's recording a sports practice I'm part of.
Are there any video recording apps that auto-switch to particular lense? Or other ways to make the wide angle lense the default?
So far I've tried Filmic, Open Camera, Secure Camera (by GrapheneOS), Libre Camera, and ProShot. ProShot has come the closest it sometimes remembers the lense, but not reliably. Blackmagic Camera isn't available for my phone (Motorola Razr 2022)

My somewhat related answer to: How does the camera app find/use/integrate the various multiple cameras on each phone? may explain why you can't do what you want directly. If your existing 'hack' answer works, great, unless you are familiar with Android app development to make Open Camera do what you want. Also see: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+panorama

Thank you. I'll accept that answer should you choose to post it. I suspected the situation might be "no, there's no good API". ProShot's UI mentioned detecting hidden cameras or APIs. Also thank you for introducing me to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

I'm also content for this to be marked a duplicate of the other. I lack the privilege to do so.

In the interim, I'll try a lockout tag as plan B (old phone as stunt double)


You can create a shortcut to your camera app's relevant activity thread, e.g., via Nova Launcher...


I don't happen to have that camera feature, but if it's supported by your camera app it should show up in the list somewhere in there!
